# OpenLDAP client config, cannot log in to the server

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP on a Ubuntu 22.04 to authenticate against a central server running Ubuntu Server 20.04, however, i have found some issues i cannot solve on my own.

The server itself is running fine, i can connect to it and query it in the Ubuntu client. I mainly used [this](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=openldap&f=1) guide to install both the server and the client.

I can use `ldapsearch -x -LLL -b dc=<dc>,dc=com` to query it, but i cannot login to the users on the client, from what i have googled the problem seems to be on the client.

`/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`:

```
BASE   dc=<dc>,dc=com`
URI    ldap://192.168.x.xxx`
#SIZELIMIT 12
#TIMELIMIT 15
#DEREF never
TLS_CACERT   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd   compat systemd ldap
group    compat systemd ldap
shadow   compat ldap
gshadow  files
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session [default=1] pam_permit.so
session requisite pam_deny.so
session required pam_permit.so
session optional pam_umask.so
session required pan_unix.so
session [success=ok default=ignore] pam_ldap.so ninimun_uid=1000
session optional pam_systemd.so
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=077
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password requisite pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password [success=3 default=ignore pam_unix.so obscure pam_ldap.so try_first_pass yescrypt
password [success=1 defau1t=ignore] pam_1dap.so minimum_uid=500 try_first_pass
password requisite pam_deny.so
password required pam_permit.so
password optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth [success=3 defau1t=tgnore] pam_unix.so nullok
auth [success=1 defau1t=ignore] pam_ldap.so minimun_uid=1000 use_first_pass
auth requisite pam_deny.so
auth required pam_permit.so
auth optional pam_cap.so
```

Let me know if any other file/information is necessary.